# Why is a display resolution missing from Ubuntu on Xorg environment, but not from Ubuntu environment?

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr, randr

I run Ubuntu 22.10 on Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 2020. Its graphic card is Mesa Intel® Xe (TGL GT2). I noticed the following:

- When I log in to the Ubuntu desktop environment (which is default), I can choose the 1440x900 resolution (16x10 aspect ratio).
- When I log in to Ubuntu on Xorg desktop environment, the 1440x900 resolution is not offered as an option.

I see the same behaviour through both the GUI (Settings > Display), and command line (xrandr). Also, the above resolution was available on Xorg in Ubuntu 22.04.

Why is this happenning? How can I re-enable 1440x900 resolution for the Xorg environment again?

Comment: Do you have xserver-xorg-video-intel installed?  If so, try uninstalling it, to use the modesetting driver.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @AdamSelker, I did have xserver-xorg-video-intel installed. I uninstalled it just now, rebooted the computer, but my issue perissts. Is it sufficient to only `apt purge` this package, or should I do anything else?

Comment: I think that should be enough to switch you to the modesetting driver.  Dang, was worth a try.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the resolution, like in this question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i

Answer (score 1):

The `drm_info` tool from the package `drm-info` can help you investigate this.

It's output is very verbose, so I wrote a tool to digest this more easily:

[gfxi](https://github.com/canonical/gfxi)

You can either trawl through the output of `drm_info` or use the `gfxi` tool to see what connectors, controllers, planes are active:

```
$ gfxi --annotate connector
236 # DP (connected)
249 # HDMI-A (disconnected)
255 # HDMI-A (disconnected)
```

```
$ gfxi --annotate crtc
80  # 3840x2160+0+0
131 # 0x0+0+0
182 # 0x0+0+0
233 # 0x0+0+0
```

```
$ gfxi --annotate plane type:Primary
31  # Primary (3840x2160)
82  # Primary (0x0)
133 # Primary (0x0)
184 # Primary (0x0)
```

If the resolutions are not as expected, search for 'Modes' in the `drm_info` output, and see if your desired resolution is listed or not, for the specific connector that is in use.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having trouble following these instructions. "see if your desired resolution is listed or not" it is not. So how did this knowledge help me resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Buggy hardware/drivers can cause problems when detecting your monitor's correct resolution. For example, the EDID data block queried from your monitor may be incorrect. Follow these steps, taken from the article below, to add a screen res that is not detected:

Get primary screen name:

```
SCREENNAME=$(xrandr | grep "connected primary" | awk '{print $1}')
```

Calculate the required modeline for 1440x900 @60Hz:

```
MODELINE=$(cvt 1440 900 60 | grep Modeline | awk '{sub($1 FS, ""); print $0}')
```

Take the output of that command and add the new mode:

```
xrandr --newmode $MODELINE
```

Associate the new mode with your primary screen:

```
xrandr --addmode $SCREENNAME $(echo $MODELINE | awk '{print$1}')
```

More information, including how to automate this, can be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Comment: This works for me on 22.04 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm assuming your code snippets are what I should copy/paste directly into terminal and execute, correct? If yes, after I paste and execute all three, I get the following error: `xrandr: cannot find mode ""1440x900_60.00""`. What now?

Comment: Also, the answers I'm still looking for are: a) Why does this disappearance happen at all? Why did my preferred resolution disappera in the first place? and b) Why would I want to automate this?

Comment: As per the listed article "Due to buggy hardware or drivers, your monitor's correct resolutions may not always be detected. For example, the EDID data block queried from your monitor may be incorrect."

Comment: All four of these commands need to be executed exactly as shown, and in the specified order.

Comment: I would not mind if my desired resolution wasn't detected. What I don't understand is why is it detected on Wayland, but not on Xorg? As for the commands, I've executed them as shown, and I'm getting this error: `xrandr: cannot find mode ""1440x900_60.00""`

Comment: what is the output of `cvt 1440 900 60`